# How to install strongloop without internet

Tags: node.js, installation, strongloop

Not everyone in our team has internet connection, but installing [strongloop](https://strongloop.com) using this command requires internet connection

```
npm install -g strongloop
```

Is there a way I can download strongloop first and then install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install -g /path/to/strongloop`

Comment: how to download strongloop to `/path/to/strongloop`?

Comment: I'm assuming someone on your team has the package? Just find someone who does and distribute it.

Comment: Someone has installed it but how to find out where it has been installed and how to distribute the same?

Comment: run `npm list -g` on their machine

Comment: so the parent folder `...\AppData\Roaming\npm` should be picked from there and copied to a central location?

Comment: Thanks, I will figure out the extraction part later